# Como capturar imagem da câmera em tempo real - C#

Tags: c#, android-camera

Como que faria para capturar a imagem em tempo real de uma câmera de um celular android por exemplo?
Quero dizer com "tempo real" seria como estivesse analisando a todo momento em que a câmera estivesse ativada para isso.